# 404 Page not found when trying to add custom javascript code in cs cart

Tags: javascript, cs-cart

i have tried to add non JavaScript code to my custom Custom HTML code and it worked nicely ..
when trying to add anything JavaScript in my admin shopping cart it redirect me to 404 page not found

here verified correct a sample of a counter in JavaScript i tried to add :

```
<div id="sfch535mrpe3dlxxkasdu781qrnxzxx1q8u"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://counter1.stat.ovh/private/counter.js?c=h535mrpe3dlxxkasdu781qrnxzxx1q8u&down=async" async></script>
<noscript><a href="https://www.freecounterstat.com" title="page counter"><img src="https://counter1.stat.ovh/private/freecounterstat.php?c=h535mrpe3dlxxkasdu781qrnxzxx1q8u" border="0" title="page counter" alt="page counter"></a></noscript>
```

the company of cs-cart suggested thirty part addon must uninstalled , i done that without success ..

Answer (score 0):

i had to goto ftp and enter the code manually in used themed template file index.tpl between

`<head></head>`

with {literal} code here {/literal} and it worked finally .